# How to disable Oculus Rift DK2 gyro in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gyroscope, oculus

i'm working on a setup for the Oculus Rift DK2 with a bigger tracking area. Disabling the position tracking is no problem. But I am not able to disable the gyroscope. 
I'm using the OVRCameraRig prefab. I tried to disable the function

```
UpdateAnchors();
```

in the Update() function. But the rotation is still updated.
I went through all the other scripts of OVR and disabled several functions, but the the roation-update by gyro is still working.

I found a solution here [OVR wiki](http://wiki.etc.cmu.edu/unity3d/index.php/Oculus_Rift) but I can not find the setOrientation() function...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: Unity v5.2.3f1, Oculus Utilities v0.1.2.0, OVRPlugin v0.1.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

These two techniques are suggested [on the Oculus forums](https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=19863&start=40#p305514):

Add to the end of UpdateAnchors() in OVRCameraRig.cs:

```
trackingSpace.FromOVRPose(centerEyeAnchor.ToOVRPose().Inverse());
```

Add in an Awake function and set this script to [execute first](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html):

```
OVRPlugin.rotation = false;
```

I tried both in a clean project with the Oculus Utilities v0.1.2, Unity 5.1.2p3, and Oculus Runtime 0.6. The first created a strobing effect which wasn't acceptable and the second didn't work at all. Maybe it will work for you with a newer version of Unity.

I also tried hacking it by overriding the camera's rotation to zero in Update, LateUpdate, and EndOfFrame but that did not work either. Maybe the Unity order of events can be manipulated to solve this.

Comment: I 've got the same effects on both solutions. With different Unity versions. For now I went back to Unity 4.6.9 an the 0.6.2 SDK from Oculus.
This is not the solution I want to use. I know the issue of simulation sickness by disabling the "headtracking" but I don't know the interest of making the life awkward for developers like this. (in a DK!)
We are using an own tracking-system to get a bigger tracking-area...

Comment: Completely understand the use case, although I'm sure its not Oculus' top priority. From the thread I linked it sounds like its coming soon so hopefully your solution will get you through until then.